# Now that chrome forces extensions to be downloaded using the webstore, is there a chance to migrate my old users?

Tags: google-chrome

I have an extension that I used to host on my server.
I have an update url pointing to my server where updates are automatically published to the users.

The newest chrome version does not allow installation of extensions over 3rd party urls, they need to be hosted in the webstore.

If I do that, do all users need to re-add the extension, or can they somehow migrate seemlessly to recieve future updates from the webstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish to the webstore, with the same id, by importing your existing key:

Put your private key as 'key.pem' in the root yof your extension directory and zip it along the extension. It will be removed upon upload.

Republish the old crx with update_url set to:

http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx

This way it will be seamless.

(Source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-extensions/3vvygtEajMQ%5B1-25%5D
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-apps/qZ5PXH2KzPs%5B1-25%5D )

Answer (score 2):

You can still use 3rd party .crx extensions, themes, apps, etc.

But the file must be downloaded to a local folder and then dragged into the extensions manager (chrome://chrome/extensions/).